# How can I take a server with several Apache VirtualHosts, and add Drupal from Ubuntu "aptitude install drupal7"?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, drupal

I have a server that has several Apache VirtualHosts, and I want to add Drupal. I see that my installing drupal7 (under Ubuntu Raring on an EC2 host) let Drupal set up camp in /usr/share/drupal7. What I'm not as sure of is how to add a VirtualHost for Drupal without disturbing the existing sites.

At https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Drupal, the last command before restarting Apache2 is:

```
sudo cp /etc/drupal/7/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/drupal.conf
```

I haven't run this, partially because I don't know globally if this means "Start over on a Drupal host."

How can I add an additional VirtualHost that will be Drupal-driven while leaving existing sites untouched?

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this, this is against the way Apache is configured on Debian-derived systems.

If you look into `apache2.conf`, it will add a global alias `/drupal7` pointing to `/usr/share/drupal7` and set a few options for this directory for all configured vhosts.

Unless you want a `/drupal7` alias on your vhosts, all this should be done inside the configuration for a virtual host and not just dropped into some config directory.

If you indeed want this for all vhosts, you should put this file into `/etc/apache2/conf.d` instead of `mod-enabled` which should only contain symlinks to `mod-available` and activate Apache binary modules.